# unable to connect between curl in host and golang server in docker alpine

Tags: docker, go, curl

golang code:

```golang
fmt.Println("server starting...")
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    name, _ := os.Hostname()
    resp := fmt.Sprintf("hit %s", name)
    w.Write([]byte(resp))
})

http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8080", nil)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
COPY ./server .
CMD [ "./server" ]
```

Then run it:

```sh
$ docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 server
server starting...
```

It works in container(after curl installed):

```
$ docker exec 3c3 -it curl localhost:8080
hit 3c398d80ca79
```

**But it doesn't work in host**:

```sh
$ curl localhost:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
$ nc localhost 8080 
$ # nc exit immediatly
```

If I run `nc -l -p 8080` instead of `./server`:

```sh
$ docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 alpine:latest nc -l -p 8080
```

and run it in host:

```sh
$ curl localhost:8080
```

Then I can get request in container, and everthing works well.

**So what's the problem when curl the golang server in alpine image?**

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `EXPOSE 8080` in your dockerfile

Answer (score -1):

I use `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)` instead, everthing works well!